# Checking if variable is not empty in NodeJS CoffeeScript vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, npm, sails.js

In Sails.js docs, database query is executed with .exec(err, result), and we check if(!result) to check if the result is empty.

I am building an npm module with CoffeeScript. When it is translated to JavaScript, the condition if(result) succeeds even if the result is empty!

Does it have something to do with CoffeeScript?

```
Bruteforce.find
    where:
      _id: _id
  .exec (err, doc) ->
    typeof callback == 'function' &&  callback(err, null) if err
    data = {}
    if doc && new Date(doc.expires).getTime() < new Date().getTime()
      Bruteforce.destroy
        _id: _id
      .exec (err) ->
        return callback(err) if err
        return callback()
    if doc // condition succeeds even doc is empty
      data.count = doc.count
      data.lastRequest = new Date(doc.lastRequest)
      data.firstRequest = new Date(doc.firstRequest)
      typeof callback == 'function' && callback(null, data)
    else
      typeof callback == 'function' && callback(null, null)
```

Translated JavaScript

```
return Bruteforce.find({
      where: {
        _id: _id
      }
    }).exec(function(err, doc) {
      var data;
      if (err) {
        typeof callback === 'function' && callback(err, null);
      }
      data = {};
      if (doc && new Date(doc.expires).getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
        Bruteforce.destroy({
          _id: _id
        }).exec(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(err);
          }
          return callback();
        });
      }
      if (doc) { // condition succeeds even doc is empty
        data.count = doc.count;
        data.lastRequest = new Date(doc.lastRequest);
        data.firstRequest = new Date(doc.firstRequest);
        return typeof callback === 'function' && callback(null, data);
      } else {
        return typeof callback === 'function' && callback(null, null);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Define "empty". Do you mean you're getting an empty array? And I guarantee you it's not a CoffeeScript issue. CoffeeScript translates perfectly fine to Javascript. It's like asking if there's a problem between Portuguese and Spanish.

Comment: So what specifically is `doc` when you expect `if(doc)` to not succeed? Also, you'd normally say `f?(x)` instead of `typeof f == 'function' && f(x)` in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Doc is literally empty as empty string... Not null not undefined and not empty array

Comment: @user963991 `doc` must have something in it to be considered "truthy", even it's only whitespace. It will only be false if it's (and I'm probably forgetting something here): `false`, `''`, `undefined`, `null`, `NaN` or `0`. Any other value will be true.